# "Now on Tap" feature test on emulator Android

Tags: android, google-now, android-6.0-marshmallow

Since Google announces the "Now on Tap" feature for contextual search from different app, in M Developer Preview so I just wanted the test out the feature. I have updated the emulator (using genymotion) to M. but I am not able to test this.

Anyone has Idea about it?

Answer (score 6):

We were told in the Google I|O presentations that Now on Tap would not be part of the M Developer Preview, at least at this time.